# How to dispatch value onChange

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatch

I'm building a search component and I've set up my actions and reducers and so on... but I can't figure out how to dispatch an event in my component. What should be inside the onChangeValue attribute?

Here's the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getListOfUsers, clearDetails } from "../../actions/actions";
import SearchBar from "../../components/search/search";

const SearchBarContainer = onChangeValue => {
  return <SearchBar onChangeValue={onChangeValue} id="search" icon="search" />;
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onChangeValue: e => {
      dispatch(getListOfUsers(e.target.value));
      dispatch(clearDetails());
    }
  };
};

const connected = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SearchBarContainer);

export default connected;
```

Comment: Instead of `onChangeValue` use `this.props.onChangeValue` within `SearchBarContainer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SearchBarContainer` is a functional component and hence it won't have `state` or `this` variable. You need to get them from the props. Also dispatch function `onChangeValue` is available as a prop to the container.

```
const SearchBarContainer = ({ onChangeValue, value }) => {
  return (
    <SearchBar
      onChangeValue={onChangeValue}
      value={value}
      id="search"
      icon="search"
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Can't understand how I missed that out, tired I guess :D

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<SearchBar
      onChangeValue={onChangeValue}
      value={this.state.value}
      id="search"
      icon="search"
    />
```

to

```
<SearchBar
          onChangeValue={this.props.onChangeValue}
          value={this.state.value}
          id="search"
          icon="search"
        />
```